# Как получить html страницу при запросе к avito через requests?

Tags: python, requests

Мне нужно через requests получить положительный ответ 200 с html  страницей от avito, раньше это работало, но видимо защита усилилась. Знаю что для парсинга есть api и безголовые браузеры по типу selenium, но мне нужно именно через requests. User-Agent добавлял и все остальные заголовки которые нашел у запроса через инструментах разработчика в браузере. Куки тоже пробовал, но в браузере и без них страница  нормально грузит.
Но я получаю статус ответа 403, нет доступа.

Comment: Я думаю это не возможно, можно получить страницу целиком, затем парсить уже ее

Comment: это понятно, сейчас поправлю